# Samsung galaxy note not taking xml file from layout-large after updating to android 4

Tags: android

In my app, I have small, normal and large layout. Initially, when I buy Samsung Galaxy Note, it comes with android 2.3.3, I tested my app in Samsung Galaxy Note, at that time it takes layout form layout-large and all works fine.

But once I updated my device to android 4. It started taking layout form layout-normal, and as a result of this some of my page alignment changes. So I want to know why this happens, is there any way to fix this out?

Comment: put all image resources in “drawable-large-hdpi” folder for note: http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/android-ui-design-tips-for-samsung-galaxy-note/

Answer (score 4):

I played a bit with `getResources().getConfiguration();` in `onCreate` of my `MainActivity`, and found out, that the device is asuming its smallestWidth with 400dp, so I took my Layout for the Galaxy Note in a **layout-sw400dp** folder and it worked. On the device is Android 4.0.3 installed.

Comment: many phones have width of 400dp. this may not be close enough.

Answer (score 2):

The device is still reporting back the same display metrics. The density/screen width & height have not change. But when you upgraded to ICS (Android 4) it started to interpret the display metrics as a Normal size screen, and Gingerbread (Android 2.3) would say these exact same display metrics are Large size screen.

The way to fix this problem, is to target the Samsung Galaxy Note and other screens that fall into this weird category, is to create a layout named:

```
layout-large-port-xhdpi-1280x800
```

And put either your Large or Normal layout in that resource. This will force your Samsung Galaxy Note to use the layout you like, and with either OS version.

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the size groups ( layout-small, layout-normal, layout-large and layout-xlarge ) are deprecated and you should instead use the sw<N>dp configuration qualifier to define the smallest available width required by your layout resources. For example, if your layout requires at least 600dp of screen width, you should place it in layout-sw600dp/.

Reference : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: so how about if i run my app in 2.3 wherein i have the sw in resources? i tested it is still using the layout-large

Comment: Actually this is the best answer and should be accepted as the right answer. AFAIK all the large and xlarge devices are supporting now the new qualifiers. Galaxy Note I has official upgrades to ICS and JB. For smaller screens yo can use the old qualifiers, like layout-normal and layout-small.

Answer (score 0):

You can use layout-sw400dp-land or layout-sw400dp.

Works fine with Galaxy Note 1 even with Cianogenmod ROM.